# DNSSEC - Recommended parameters

Tags: dnssec

Does anybody know which could be the recommended values for RRSIG validity period and resign interval?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

RRSIG validity period is (by default) 30 days.  auto-resigning takes place at 3/4 of validity period.

Unless you have a need to change these, the defaults are pretty solid.

[I work for ISC, maintainers of BIND and ISC DHCP]

Knobee / AlanC